# Pandas sum of column overflow on Windows

Tags: windows, pandas, sum, overflow, int64

I'm developing an app that must be executed in a Windows Server (2012 R2). When I run it locally (Win 7), It looks fine, but when I run it in the server I had negative results when it supposed to be positive:

```
DataFrame.column.sum()
```

I read that's because [there is a bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15453) between Python 2.7 and some Windows versions.

The problem is there I have a lot of parts in the code where I use  `pandas.col.sum()` and a few of the columns are `dtype = int64`, is there a way to solve this? maybe changing the `dtype` when I read the df?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround based on this [answer](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15453#issuecomment-296789333)

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: s = pd.Series([2**31])

In [3]: s.sum()
Out[3]: -2147483648

In [4]: from pandas.core import nanops

In [5]: nanops._USE_BOTTLENECK
Out[5]: True

In [6]: nanops._USE_BOTTLENECK = False

In [7]: s.sum()
Out[7]: 2147483648
```